# What is the the purpose of having both $PATH and $path?

Tags: linux-mint, zsh, path

I'm using Mint 20.1 (**update**: I also use `zsh` as my shell) , and I notice that there are two very similar environment variables dealing with path:

- `$PATH`, which lists every path directory, using colons as separators
- `$path`, which lists the same directorys, but using spaces as separators

Why is that? What is the purpose of each variant? AFAIK, everyone recommends that changes to path should be committed to `$PATH`; is that right?

Comment: Is this in `zsh`? "Everyone recommends" because many other shells use `$PATH` only.

Comment: Yes! it is `zsh`. I'll add that to the main question. Is `$path` specific to `zsh` then?

Comment: @steeldriver it does answer, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: `$path` doesn't have the directories separated with spaces. It's an array, directories are the distinct elements of that array. `print $path` prints them separated with spaces only because `print` prints it's argument separated with spaces by default. With `print -l $path`, they would be printed on separate lines, with `print -C2` on two columns, etc.